# Android pay rooted device

Tags: android-pay

I have installed the Android pay in the UK but I cannot add a card because my device is rooted. I have xposed framework and I have installed the no device check module. I tried to disable root feature in the su also. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your rooted device contains some error with OS(Does not support all functionality of google play and google wallet) the android pay will not work properly.

Android pay didn't provide all functionality in UK so please check your card provider too. But from few last years android pay gave lot of functionalities and increase the card provider to support the android pay , So try with another card in android pay .

Comment: Thank you but the root was the only problem. I reinstall the factory software and the Android Pay works now. If the phone is rooted the Android Pay does not work.